# Questions about Heisenberg lie algebra and it's representation.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am learning the representation of lie algebra and I have met the following question with no clues...Can anyone help me to answer or give me a hint?

The question is as follows:

The the matrix realization of Heisenberg Lie algebra is $$H= \bigg\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    0&x&y  \\
    0&0&z  \\
    0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}: \ x,y,z \in F\bigg\}$$

Then consider $V=F^3$ as a representation of $H$, where the action of any element x $\in H $on any vector $v \in V $ is by matrix multiplication.

Then prove than $V$ has a unique maximal proper $H$-submodule $W$. And what is $V/W$ as a representation of $H$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Let $v \in V$ be an arbitrary element of $V$, and write $v = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$. What is $Hv$?

Comment: Thank you sir! $Hv$ is then $[a,b,0]^T$ for some $a,b \in F$. So the set of  $[a,b,0]^T$ is actually a 2-dimentional submodule, which is clearly proper H-submodule with maximal dimension? But How can I prove it is unique?

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not $c=0$ and whether or not $b=0$. But what you should notice is that these "principal submodules" are nested.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused...If c ≠ 0 and b ≠ 0...what can I say about the H-submodule? And if c=0, can I say dim$V$ is 2, and in turn the H-submodule is NOT proper?

Comment: It seems you kind of disappeared?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, Sorry for the late reply...I was too busy in preparing mid-term and some projects. I just got some time to read your answer which is very helpful! Thanks again and I will definitely update my answer for the $V/W$ after I solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $v \in V$, we consider the $H$-submodule of $V$ generated by $v$ - let's call this submodule $M_v$. In general, for $H$ an arbitrary Lie algebra and $V$ an arbitrary $H$-module, $H$ doesn't contain an identity and isn't necessarily closed under composition of the module action, so this object looks like $$M_v = Fv + Hv + H(H v) + H(H(H(v))) + \cdots.$$ In this case $V$ is the defining representation of $H$ and $H$ does happen to be closed under composition of its action on $V$, so we just have $M_v = Fv+Hv$.

Note that every submodule of $V$ can be written as $M_{v_1} + \cdots + M_{v_k}$ for some $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in V$, so to understand the structure of all submodules of $V$, it is enough to understand the structure of those generated by one element.

If we write $$v = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix},$$ then we can compute $Fv+Hv$ for each possible $v$:

- $c \neq 0$. Then $M_v = V$.
- $c = 0$, but $b \neq 0$. Then $M_v = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ 0\end{bmatrix} : x, y \in F\right\}$.
- $c = 0$ and $b=0$, but $a \neq 0$. Then $M_v = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}x \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} : x \in F\right\}$.
- $a=b=c=0$. Then $M_v = \{0\}$.

Observe that the submodules generated by one element are nested inside each other, so they are all of the submodules of $V$. And the largest of them that is not equal to $V$ is the unique maximal submodule of $V$. I'll leave it to you to compute the action on the quotient space $V/W$.

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for your answer and sorry for this very late reply...that is very rude of me...It appears to me that $M_v$ = $Fv+Hv+H(Hv)$ since $H(Hv)$ is the span of $[a,0,0]^T$. But the solution should remain the same...

Comment: Also, for the quotient, since the representation of quotient is defined by $x*(v+W)=xv+W$ for $x \in H, V \in V $and since $xv$ = ${[a,b,0]^T}$, so $xv+W$ is $W$ itself.  so the action of $V/M$ plays an invariant role.Am I correct? thanks!

Comment: No worries; I don't think you were rude at all. Re "It appears to me that $M_v = F v + H v + H(H v)$": My point is that $H(Hv) \subset Hv$, so the presence of $H(Hv)$ in the sum is superfluous.

Comment: $xv \in \begin{bmatrix} * & * & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ is true; it's not $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$ necessarily. But the important feature is that $xv \in W$, so $xv+W = W$. This shows that $V/W$ is the trivial representation - every element of $H$ acts by zero on $V/W$.

Comment: Thanks! I now can totally understand :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it!